# Property and methodoverride conversion from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties, overloading

I’m studying both VB.NET and C#
I have the following code in VB that I converted in C#.
The code have a Form, a base class Vehicle and a derived class Car.
In VB, the base class Vehicle as 4 properties declared with only one line without set & get, while in C# I first had to declare the variables, then the 4 properties with set & get methods (and lot of lines). Is it the correct way or there is a simple one like in VB?
VB.NET

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myCar As New Car()
        myCar.Make = "Ferrari"
        myCar.Model = "Testa rossa"
        myCar.Year = 1999
        myCar.Color = "Red"

        PrintVehicleDetails(myCar)
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintVehicleDetails(ByVal _vehicle As Vehicle)
        Console.WriteLine("Here is the car's details: {0}", _vehicle.FormatMe())
    End Sub
End Class


Public MustInherit Class Vehicle
    Public Property Make As String

    Public Property Model As String

    Public Property Year As Integer

    Public Property Color As String

    Public MustOverride Function FormatMe() As String

End Class


Public Class Car
    Inherits Vehicle
    Public Overrides Function FormatMe() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}",
                              Me.Make, Me.Model, Me.Year, Me.Color)
    End Function
End Class
```

C#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.make = "Ferrari";
        myCar.model = "Testa rossa";
        myCar.year = 1999;
        myCar.color = "Red";

        PrintVehicleDetails(myCar);
    }

    private void PrintVehicleDetails(Vehicle _vehicle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is the car's details: {0}", _vehicle.FormatMe());
    }
}    

abstract class Vehicle
{
    string Make = "";
    string Model = "";
    int Year = 0;
    string Color ="";

    public string make
    {
        get
        { return Make; }

        set
        { Make = value; }
    }

    public string model
    {
        get
        { return Model; }

        set
        { Model = value; }
    }

    public int year
    {
        get
        { return Year; }

        set
        { Year = value; }
    }

    public string color
    {
        get
        { return Color; }

        set
        { Color = value; }
    }

    abstract public string FormatMe();
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override string FormatMe()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", 
                             this.make, this.model, this.year, this.color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also directly define property like below

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public string Make { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Model{ get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int Year{ get; set; } = 0;

    public string Color { get; set; } ;
}
```